# IFrame is not centre aligned

Tags: css, html, razor

I'm using following outlook code which embeds an Outlook calendar in my website, but its aligned to the left by default. Can you please let me know to make it centre aligned to the screen.

Thanks

Code I'm using is

```html
<style unselectable="on">
#wrap {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#frame {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}
#frame {
-ms-zoom:0.7;
}
</style>
<div id="wrap" unselectable="on">
    <iframe id="frame" src="[paste in here the link that outlook.com provides for you ... in between the quotes and without the brackets]"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for center align set margin:0 auto to it's parent (if parent has width in px) or iframe.

```
#wrap {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to #wrap in your css

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oxugdht0/).